# jQuery - If all Child elements have same class add additional class to another element on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I would like to be able to check using jQuery if all child elements share the same class. If all child elements have the same class I would then like to apply an additional class to another element on the page that is not a direct child but the closest h4.

The HTML elements in question are in the attached image. The code is auto generated by a plugin.

Currently I am looking for any elements that contain 0 and the class no items is applied. This can be seen in the screenshot.

The h4 at the top of the image is the element that needs a class adding to it if all children have the class of "no-items"

Basic HTML Example

```
<div>
<h4>This is the element that needs a class if all li's have the class of no-items</h4>
<ul>
    <li class="no-items">0</li>
    <li class="no-items">0</li>
    <li class="">1</li>
    <li class="no-items">0</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

New Code tried and results shown in the screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BURfI.png)

```
$('.woof_container_inner h4').addClass(function(){
if( $(this).next('ul').find('li').length === $(this).next('ul').find('li.noitems').length ) return 'someclass';
```

})

"someclass" should only be applied to the H4 element if all li's within the ul have the class of no items. If not do nothing.

Comment: `$('ul > li:not(.no-items)').length > 0` would tell you if any of then do not have that class.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your input, if possible can you expand on this more? And how it could be applied to the closet H4. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code from @j08691 answer with some small edits pleased to say the following code works for me.

```
$('.woof_container_inner h4').addClass(function(){
if( $(this).next('div').find('li').length === $(this).next('div').find('li.noitems').length ) return 'no-heading';
```

})

I have combined the above code with the following so It executes after each Ajax filter is selected.

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(){

$('.woof_container_inner h4').addClass(function(){
    if( $(this).next('div').find('li').length === $(this).next('div').find('li.noitems').length ) return 'no-heading';
})

});

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
$('h4').addClass(function(){
    if( $(this).next('ul').find('li').length === $(this).next('ul').find('li.no-items').length ) return 'someclass';
})
```

This would be applied to all h4 elements on the page so you may need to make it more specific.

What it does is look for an h4 element and add a class if the number of list items in the list that follows it equals the number of list items with the no-items class.

Comment: Hi thanks for your input, unfortunately I cant seem to be target each ul individually. I will try attach another image to the question to show more of the code. Currently the class gets added to each h4 whether or not the closest list of elements all have the class of .noitems or not. Is there a way of looping the code for each instance thats found or something similar?

Comment: The code you originally posted doesn't match the image you added which is why.

Comment: Could you offer anymore advice or are you not able to provide a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @MrSpurs Try changing `$(this).next('ul').find('li')` to `$(this).next('div').find('li')` in my above example

Comment: Thanks but this still seems to add the class of someclass to every h4 even if the Li's do not share the same class..... Tell a lie I think it may be sorted!

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve] and not just an image of the actual code